# A difficulty in understanding the proof of boundary theorem in G&P.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, intersection-theory, transversality

The theorem and its proof is given below:

[image]

But I could not understand the last line in the proof in particular:

Why $F^{-1}(Z)$ is a compact one dimensional manifold with boundary? And why this leads to

(#$\partial F^{-1}(Z)$ =  #$f^{-1}(Z))$?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $F^{-1}(Z)$ is a manifold because of transversality.

Comment: By which theorem and why it is one dimensional?@LordSharktheUnknown